# How can we use Application Insight telemetry data in Azure search?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights, azure-cognitive-search

I am trying to find the way to use the application insight logged data in azure search. For now I am able to export data from Application Insight to Blob storage. But when I am trying to fetch it from azure search then I am getting data related to file not the real data stored in file. Also, in every 0.5-1 minute new file is being created in blob.

Could you please help me to find the way to use the application insight data in azure search?

I don't want to use SQL database as data source in azure search because might be some performance issue will occur if I schedule it to get the data from SQL database in every hour and also it will not be synced.

Please suggest.

Comment: What's your end game with this data?  Would you be able to use the [REST API](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/) to do what you want to do?

Comment: Hi Brendan, thanks for quick response. At the end I want to use the Application Insight data in azure search and want to implement autosuggest feature in my application.

Comment: @BrendanGreen Any other suggestion?